# Convert to new Name

Tags: c#, converters, datacontract

we are using the XML from the DataContractSerializer to store the user settings into the Database. However we now have to change the name and the Type of one Property. 
Old Property

```
[DataMember(Name = "Settings")]
public System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary Settings { get; set; }
```

result in this XML =>

```
<Settings xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <a:KeyValueOfanyTypeanyType>
      <a:Key i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">blue</a:Value>
   </a:KeyValueOfanyTypeanyType>
</Settings>
```

New Property

```
[DataMember(Name = "UserSettings")]
public Dictionary<long, Object> UserSettings { get; set; }
```

result in this XML =>

```
<UserSettings xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"> 
   <a:KeyValueOflonganyType> 
      <a:Key>1</a:Key>
      <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">blue</a:Value>     
   </a:KeyValueOflonganyType>
</UserSettings>
```

Is there way to tell the DataContractSerializer hey it is still the some data but it looks a bit different? To Implement ISerializable is not on option because I want to convert the Data ones and then no more.

thx for helping

Michael

Comment: Just change the DataMember Name to "Settings" for the `UserSettings` property, I would imagine.  If that doesn't work you can massage the data in your database.. its a one-time change that shouldn't cost much.

Comment: Hi Sam Axe, this works only on way. I have to deserialize the Data with [DataMember(Name = "Settings")] and serialize it with [DataMember(Name = "UserSettings")] in one step

But I think you are right! it is better to Change the XML by Hand - THX